# Tooltip in VegaLite only shows first data of data set

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph, vega-lite

Im trying to build a vega lite graph with multiple lines and a dynamic tooltip showing up on hover. (kind like this [example](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip.html))

My tooltip only shows the first data of my dataset and refuses to be dynamic.

Here is the Spec for the graph (can play with it here : [vega lite playground](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/custom/vega-lite) )

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {
    "customFormatTypes": true,
    "font": "BNPP,Arial",
    "legend": {"disable": true}
  },
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "background": "null",
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "monotone"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "axis": {
            "domainColor": "lightgray",
            "tickColor": "lightgray",
            "labelColor": "#af4200",
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "labelOverlap": true,
            "grid": false
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "mileage",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {
            "gridDash": [5, 5],
            "domainColor": "lightgray",
            "tickColor": "lightgray",
            "labelColor": "#797979",
            "grid": false
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "nominal",
          "field": "symbol",
          "scale": {
            "domain": ["consumedMileage", "idealConsumption"],
            "range": ["#af4200", "#797979"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeDash": [4, 4],
        "strokeCap": "round",
        "color": "#797979"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 1666386000000,
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "domainColor": "lightgray",
            "tickColor": "lightgray",
            "labelColor": "#af4200",
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "labelOverlap": true,
            "grid": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "strokeWidth": 1,
        "strokeDash": [4, 4],
        "strokeCap": "round",
        "color": "#797979"
      },
      "encoding": {"y": {"datum": 8000, "type": "quantitative"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "color": "#af4200",
        "dy": -4,
        "align": "left",
        "angle": -90
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"datum": "#PlannedContractEndDate"},
        "y": {"datum": 10},
        "x": {"datum": 1666386000000, "type": "temporal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "baseline": "top",
        "color": "#af4200",
        "dy": 4,
        "align": "left"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"datum": "#RentalContractMileage"},
        "y": {"datum": 8000},
        "x": {"datum": 1664744400000, "type": "temporal"}
      }
    },
     {
      "transform": [{"pivot": "symbol", "value": "mileage", "groupby": ["date"]}],
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.3, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "date"},
          {"field": "consumedMileage"},
          {"field": "idealConsumption"}
        ]
      },
      "params": [{
        "name": "hover",
        "select": {
          "type": "point",
          "fields": ["idealConsumption"],
          "nearest": true,
          "on": "mouseover",
          "clear": "mouseout"
        }
      }]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "symbol": "consumedMileage",
        "date": "Sun, 02 Oct 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 5000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "idealConsumption",
        "date": "Sun, 02 Oct 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 6000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "consumedMileage",
        "date": "Sun, 06 Nov 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 8000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "idealConsumption",
        "date": "Sun, 06 Nov 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 7000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "consumedMileage",
        "date": "Sun, 13 Nov 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 15000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "idealConsumption",
        "date": "Sun, 13 Nov 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 7200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Version used :
"vega": "5.22.1",
"vega-embed": "6.21.0",
"vega-lite": "5.6.0",

If somebody have a lead on why this behaviour happend and how to manage this it would be wonderfull.
Thank you.

Comment: Figured this out.
Was missing 
"x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"}
in the tooltip layer. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Which line should show the tooltip?

The code below is the culprit. It is rendering nothing apart from a useless tooltip. No rule mark is being rendered as you haven't specified a positional encoding. Why do you pivot the data?

```
   {
      "transform": [{"pivot": "symbol", "value": "mileage", "groupby": ["date"]}],
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.3, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "date"},
          {"field": "consumedMileage"},
          {"field": "idealConsumption"}
        ]
      },
      "params": [{
        "name": "hover",
        "select": {
          "type": "point",
          "fields": ["idealConsumption"],
          "nearest": true,
          "on": "mouseover",
          "clear": "mouseout"
        }
      }]
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for asking.
I just added a VegaLite official example showing the tooltip mechanic im trying to implement. 
The pivot is used to create field consumedMileage and idealComsumption.
For other reasons, i organized my data like this :
{
        "symbol": "consumedMileage",
        "date": "Sun, 02 Oct 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 5000
      },
      {
        "symbol": "idealConsumption",
        "date": "Sun, 02 Oct 2022 23:00:00",
        "mileage": 6000
      }